# Pandas apply runs extra time when return a series

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Below is my test code:

```
# coding: utf8

import pandas as pd

def main():

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
        'age': [23, 33, 29],
    })
    print('Pandas verson is', pd.__version__)
    print(df)

    print(' return tuple '.center(80, '='))
    df_out = df.apply(calc_discount, axis=1)
    print(df_out)

    print(' return series '.center(80, '='))
    df_out = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(calc_discount(row)), axis=1)
    print(df_out)    

def calc_discount(row):
    print('~~~ row ~~~')
    label = row['name'][0] + '_label'
    discount = row['age'] // 3
    return label, discount


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

And here's the result for your reference:

```
Pandas verson is 1.0.5
  name  age
0   AA   23
1   BB   33
2   CC   29
================================= return tuple =================================
~~~ row ~~~
~~~ row ~~~
~~~ row ~~~
0     (A_label, 7)
1    (B_label, 11)
2     (C_label, 9)
dtype: object
================================ return series =================================
~~~ row ~~~
~~~ row ~~~
~~~ row ~~~
~~~ row ~~~
         0   1
0  A_label   7
1  B_label  11
2  C_label   9
```

When the apply function returns a tuple, the `calc_discount` function is called 3 times as expected.
but when I changed the return type, the function call becomes a little strange.

Any idea why the `apply` executes extra one more time when it returns a pd.Series?

Thank you very much~

Comment: My first intutition is that the `.apply` function is called also for the `.name` of the pandas `series` and it is treated as a row. If you use `pd.Series(print('row'))` the first row is printed twice.

Comment: This is really bizarre and I'm quite intrigued. I've tried so many things on it but I'm getting more and more confused. For instance, if your function is returning single object, then the function is getting called an extra time! I've no clue why, but change the return statement as `return [label, discount]` in `calc_discount` and even the first apply will call an extra time; and if you `lambda` in `apply` returns two values, then the apply gets called only three times!.